# matplotlib Violin Plot from pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas data frame with two columns, ArrDelay (an integer value) and Month (an integer between 1 and 12 representing month).

I am trying to create a violin plot with a separate "violin" for each month.

However, using the following code:

```
flights_subset = flights[["ArrDelay","Month"]].values

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.violinplot(flights_subset)
plt.show()
```

Gives me a plot with two "violins" one for ArrDelay and one for Month (I believe).

How can I create the desired plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using the following code:

```
flights_subset = []

for x in np.unique(flights[["Month"]].values):
    flights_subset.append(flights[flights["Month"] == x]["ArrDelay"].values)

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.violinplot(flights_subset, positions=np.unique(flights[["Month"]].values))
plt.show()
```